# Why does Safari not take the "padding" correctly?

Tags: css

Here is a simple sketch:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
}

body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello, world!
</div>
```

If you compare this page in Chrome and Safari, you can see that the space between the top of the font and the right border of the page is completely different. Why is it like that? Is there a way to fix it globally?

Comment: Can you show a complete, minimal (X)HTML file that shows the behaviour you observed? Especially the used Doctype / XML declaration, along with the content-type header used to send it to the browser.

Comment: @JohannesH. – Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. You can see this issue if you open the page of this Stack Overflow article in Chrome, and in Safari. The browser version doesn't really matter, I have tried it with many different ones, always the same issue. You also can use this fiddle to see it: https://jsfiddle.net/kcynzr13/1/

Comment: Yes. But as the snippet is not a complete HTML page, you can never rely on specific styling details to be according to the specification, as the specification only applies to syntactically correct and complete HTML. Therefore, a snippet being displayed incorrectly is not necessarily a bug in a rendering engine.